# C# Webapi POST request fails - 404 NOT FOUND

Tags: c#, ajax, rest, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a webapi Controller class with different action, GET and PUT are working fine, POST is failing the whole time and I am quite frustrated. Maybe you can give me some hints how I can solve this issue.

Controller Action:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/jobs")]
public class JobsController : ApiController
{
    [ActionName("PostInactiveStatus")]
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult PostInactiveStatus(Job job)
    {
        CsJobSchedulerEntities dataContext = new CsJobSchedulerEntities();
        try
        {
            var refJob = (from j in dataContext.Job
                          where j.JOB_ID == job.JOB_ID
                          select j).SingleOrDefault();

            refJob.JOB_ACTIVE = 0;
            refJob.JOB_MUSER = job.JOB_MUSER;
            refJob.JOB_MDATE = DateTime.Now;             

            dataContext.SaveChanges();

            var jobs = dataContext.Job.ToList();
            return Ok(jobs);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new HttpError(ex.Message)));

        }

    }
}
```

WebapiConfig class:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{key}",
        defaults: new { key = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );

    //PAM: Add Default Message Handler when Content-Type is Empty
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new DefaultContentTypeMessageHandler());  

    //PAM: Web API configuration and services
    EnableCrossSiteRequests(config);

}

private static void EnableCrossSiteRequests(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute(
        origins: "*",
        headers: "*",
        methods: "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
}
```

Client Request:

```
function removeJob(data) {  

    jQuery.support.cors = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: HOST + "api/v1/jobs/PostInactiveStatus",
        type: "Post",
        data: data,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function () {

        },
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

[image: Http Request Network request]

Error Message:

> "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   `http://localhost:59732/api/v1/jobs/PostInactiveStatus`.",
>   "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named
>   'v1'."

Where I fail?

**UPDATE:** The Controller has added the RoutePrefix for versioning the API, as stated GET and PUT are working fine.

Comment: Well for one based on route template there is no v1. What is the name of the controller that has the above action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the name of the controller is `JobsController` and that the route template defined in the OP

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{key}",
    defaults: new { key = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

is accurate, then update the ajax call to match expected route template

```
url: HOST + "api/jobs/PostInactiveStatus",
```

Other wise a new route would have to be defined for that url which includes `v1` in the route template

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "V1Api",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/{controller}/{action}/{key}",
    defaults: new { key = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{key}",
    defaults: new { key = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

**UPDATE**

based on added information, the route attribute for the action is missing. include it on the action.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v1/jobs")]
public class JobsController : ApiController {
    //POST api/v1/jobs/PostInactiveStatus
    [ActionName("PostInactiveStatus")]
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [Route("PostInactiveStatus")] //<-- this was missing
    public IHttpActionResult PostInactiveStatus(Job job) { ...}
}
```

Comment: he could also try to add `Route` attribute to api method. `[Route("api/v1/jobs/PostInactiveStatus")]`

Comment: Yes but OP didn't indicate if Attribute routing was applied to the controller.

Comment: I have added an Update, I am using the Routeprefix on Controller level for versioning purpose.

Comment: Then you are missing `[Route("PostInactiveStatus")]`

Comment: ahh...you are right :-/. I tried now but I got another problem that the simple type (Job job) passing to the controller is null!?!

Comment: That's a new question. but you can set the content type as `application/json` and `JSON.stringify` the data before sending.